# Using textmate with applications accessed through ssh

Tags: r, ssh, textmate, stata

I like using textmate to edit scripts for my analysis using R, Stata and SQL.  Recently, I've had to use our grid server environment because the datasets are too large for my computer, and the ram allocations on the grid using R and Stata are much larger than what my computer has too offer.

My current workflow is to open up these programs hosted on the grid (R and Stata) through ssh window connections.  I do my script editing in textmate, files that exist either on my computer or on my server directory.  When I want to run them in batch, I just submit the entire file through the ssh interface.  However, if I want to troubleshoot and run commands in Stata or R in real time, I have to write up my code in textmate, select it, then paste it into the ssh window hosting the state or R session.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to configure textmate such that you can just highlight in textmate and hit some shortcut keys to send the select code directly to Stata or R in the ssh sessions.

Everything I've looked up talks about how to access files to edit in textmate using ssh.  In my case, I'm looking to how to make textmate interact with server applications that are accessed using ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do.

Mounting over ssh could be an option:
http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2010/05/31/mounting-a-folder-on-osx-over-ssh/

Then you have a local dir that you can open in textmate and the files are located on the remote server, all via ssh so it should probably work.

Or use Rsync:
http://kennethreitz.com/remote-textmate-development-via-ssh-and-rsync/

If you are familiar with emacs/vim, you could use that via the ssh shell for small edits or use xemacs with X-session-forwarding over ssh. xemacs has excellent R support.

btw, what kind of analysis do you do that requires more computing power?